# I keep getting the error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column '. . . . ' in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Here is my code guys, what am I doing wrong (I am forced to use a regular Statement as opposed to the PreparedStatement class so that I can use mySQL's AES_ENCRYPT/DECRYPT methods):

DDL

```
 s.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE login ("+"user_Name CHAR(50) NOT NULL,"+"PRIMARY KEY(user_Name),"+"pass_Word CHAR(50)NOT NULL, cust_ID CHAR(10))");
```

DML

```
 public static void insertLoginData(String user_Name, String pass_Word, String cust_ID)throws IOException, SQLException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException 
 {
     . . .

     String insert="INSERT INTO login(user_Name, pass_Word, cust_ID)"
            + " VALUES("+user_Name+",AES_ENCRYPT('text',"+pass_Word+"),"+cust_ID+")";

     s.executeUpdate(insert);
```

Comment: put in more specifics. Like exact error message. You mentioned more details in other question. Secondly, before s.executeUpdate() put print statement that prints insert variable. Then try it in mysql.

Comment: Sir you are a gentleman and a scholar. . . seeing the printed SQL statement let me see for myself that I needed to add in extra quote marks.  THANK YOU!

Comment: corrected SQL entry for any others like me:  String insert="INSERT INTO login(user_Name, pass_Word, cust_ID)"
                + " VALUES ('"+username5+"',AES_ENCRYPT('text','"+password5+"'),'"+custID5+"')";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need single quotes around the column values like this:

```
  String insert="INSERT INTO login(user_Name, pass_Word, cust_ID)"
        + " VALUES('"+user_Name+"',AES_ENCRYPT('text','"+pass_Word+"'),'"+cust_ID+"')";
```

On a side note: Someone will eventually point out that this code is subject to SQL injection attack.

Comment: Incidentally, I was able to get Java’s Cipher class to work, so I didn’t have to use the mySQL internal AES_ENCRYPT/DECRYPT functions! Apparently, my cipher was not working because I kept generating two separate keys for both the encrypt () and decrypt() methods!  Dooh!  But thanks to this problem I was having I did learn a lot about SQL statements, the different errors that one can get, and most importantly the way to solve them.   
Once I realized how to get the Java Cipher class to function properly I was able to use the PreparedStatement class to avoid SQL injection problems.  Booyah!